# A problem with functions defined on positive integers.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

[image]

Where [x] denotes the greatest integer number, which does not exceed x.

I need some help please. The proof should also be at high school level. Please don’t use hard or complex things.

Comment: What does that little mark on the start of the last line mean?

Comment: I guess "prove that"

Comment: Experimenting, it seems that $f(2^k+k-2)=2^{k-1}$

Comment: Yeah. It means prove that

Comment: The answer says that f(2^k + k - 2)=(2^(k -1))^2

Comment: Oh yes yes sure, I was working with $\sqrt{f(n)}$ and forgot it

Comment: Also a hint in the book is to prove by induction that f(2^k + k - 2)=(2^(k -1))^2 and if n is not of this form (which means n is between 2^k + k - 2 and 2^(k+1) + (k+1)-2) then f(n) is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Show that if $f(n)=N^2$ then for $0\leq k\leq N$
$$\begin{align}
&f(n+2k+1)=(N+k)^2+N-k, &\lfloor\sqrt{f(n+2k+1)}\rfloor=N+k,\\
&f(n+2k+2)=(N+k)^2+2N, &\lfloor\sqrt{f(n+2k+2)}\rfloor=N+k.
\end{align}$$
Therefore, in this range, we have a perfect square only for $k=N$, i.e. $f(n+2N+1)=(2N)^2$. Hence
$$f(1)=1^2\to f(4)=2^2\to f(9)=4^2\to f(18)=8^2\to f(35)=16^2.$$
We may conclude that $f(n)$ is a perfect square if $n$ belongs to the sequence $(n_k)_{k\geq 1}=1,4,9,18,35,\dots$ , that is $n_k=2^k+k-2$.